# Active Directory: Is it possible to make the Computer$ account part of a group (for instance part of the USERS group)

Tags: windows, active-directory, file-permissions, network-shares

Essentially what the subject is saying. The problem I'm trying to solve is this:

We have a website running in IIS ver8.5 and it needs to access a network share with rigid-ish permissions schemes. Our website's app-pool employs **ApplicationPoolIdentity** and it thus employs the Computer$ account of the host machine when it attempts to access network file-shares.

The problem we are encountering is that said network shares allow access only to members of the admins + users group. The computer$ account is part of neither of the aforementioned groups, resulting in access-denied error messages when our website attempts to access any file-share paths. We were wondering whether we could make the Computer$ part-take in the users group somehow (we tried the UI but it didn't provide the option to select any Computer$ accounts).

There are other solutions to this problem but we are interested to know if the above solution has any chance of being implementable before giving plan B a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UI where you set permissions, you need to tell it to look for Computer objects. Do that by clicking the 'Object Types' button:

[image: Select Users Dialog]

Then check 'Computers'.

[image: Object Types]

Click 'OK', then you can find and add computers on your domain.

Comment: We are trying to add computers to the Users group of Active Directory. But when we click on "Object Types" the Computers checkbox is not there. Can you see said checkbox on your machine?

Comment: I don't have access to add members to the Users group on any of the domains in our environment, but I did try on a non-builtin Domain Local security group and it does show there. I also tried in the NTFS permissions on my own machine.